SYS user getting ORA-01017 (invalid username/password; logon denied) even putting right password in Oracle 19c
→ OS: Oracle Linux Server release 8.7
→ DBMS: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production - Version 19.3.0.0.0
After cloning a virtual machine that we can connect normally on sqlplus with sys user, we cannot say the same about the clone and reconfigured machine, even change sys password and putting the right one:

oracle@somedb ~]$ sqlplus sys@somecdb as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Seg Set 23 09:39:55 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Informe a senha: ERROR: ORA-01017: senha/nome do usu�rio inv�lido;
log-on negado

But I can connect with SYSTEM user and probably with the other users, on both machines:

oracle@somedb ~]$ sqlplus system@somecdb
SQL*Plus: Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on Seg Set 23 09:56:01 2024
Version 19.3.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 1982, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Informe a senha: Hor�rio do �ltimo log-in bem-sucedido: Seg Set 23
2024 09:03:09 -03:00
Conectado a: Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0

Production Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL>

The root connection is ok (sqlplus / as sysdba), but the CDB connection not - same problem happens trying to connect with SQL Developer.
How can I solve it?

I've just found the solution: recreating the password file.
Here's the command used:

[oracle@somedb ~]$ orapwd
file=/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.3/dbhome_1/dbs/orapwSOMECDB
password=somepw12! force=y

Thanks anyway.

BTW, you are allowed to tick in 24 hours

24h to tick in what?
